# CreateRemoteThread + LoadLibraryA doesn't do anything despite succeeding

Tags: c++, winapi, dll-injection

Despite the fact that memory allocation/write, finding `LoadLibraryA` address and creating a remote thread return valid (not NULL) results, absolutely nothing happens after that (mainly, the DllMain of the loaded DLL doesn't seem to get called).

```cpp
#define PROC_NAME L"TestConsole.exe"
#define DLL_NAME "TestLib.dll\0"

HANDLE GetProcessByName(const wchar_t* name);

int main()
{
    const char dllName[] = DLL_NAME;
    int dllNameSize = strlen(dllName) + 1;

    HANDLE process = GetProcessByName(PROC_NAME);

    LPVOID allocMem = VirtualAllocEx(process, NULL, dllNameSize, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    WriteProcessMemory(process, allocMem, dllName, dllNameSize, NULL);

    // Just to make sure
    char buff[20];
    ReadProcessMemory(process, allocMem, buff, dllNameSize, NULL);
    printf("Data: %s\n", buff);

    LPVOID libraryAddress =
        (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");

    HANDLE remoteThread = CreateRemoteThread(process, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)libraryAddress, allocMem, NULL, NULL);
}

HANDLE GetProcessByName(const wchar_t* name)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

    if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
        {
            if (wcscmp(entry.szExeFile, name) == 0)
            {
                return OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, entry.th32ParentProcessID);
            }
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Things I know/checked:

- The thread gets created and a valid (not null) handle is returned. Despite it nothing happens.
- I'm pretty sure that it's **not** DLL's fault. It's extremely simple, simply prints to console when it gets loaded and it works correctly when used simply with `CreateThread()`.
- Injector, DLL and the app to which I'm injecting are all 64 bit. If I chose any other platform (for all 3) everything works the same except for `CreateRemoteThread()`, which now fails.

Comment: @HansPassant How about MessageBox() Because this one doesn't work either.

Comment: Can I get a feedback on this downvote? I'd happily improve my question. A downvote doesn't tell much.

Comment: Your code is very buggy. `GetProcessByName()` is leaking the `HANDLE` from `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`, skipping the 1st file from `Process32First()`, passing the wrong process ID to `OpenProcess()`, and requesting too many access rights. `main()` is leaking the remote memory and thread. And your entire code is not doing any error handling. But most important, the file path you are passing to `LoadLibraryA()` is a *relative* path. `LoadLibraryA()` is executed in the remote process, so the DLL will be looked for relative to the *remote* EXE. Don’t use relative paths, always use absolute paths.

Comment: @QmlnR2F5 - i sure that you post your actual code, with all errors in it. *Don’t use relative paths, always use absolute paths.* - faster of all this is main reason. if want understand - attach debugger to target process, set bp to thread entry point (`LoadLibraryA`) in your case and see. are it called, what result of call. etc

Comment: @QmlnR2F5 posting minimal code without error handling would not get you downvoted. Not following [mcve] guidelines could, though. In this case, I think the downvotes are probably more due to a lack of apparent effort in trying to debug and troubleshoot the problem yourself, and expecting us to diagnose the problem without seeing the DLL code, error codes/messages, etc.

Comment: Why has the error checking been omitted from the code in the question?

Comment: To make the code at least 3x smaller @DavidHeffernan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `entry.th32ParentProcessID` is the identifier of the process that created this process (its **parent process**). which means you did inject into the parent process of the target process (explorer.exe in my test). You should use `entry.th32ProcessID` instead.

In addition, the open permission `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` used in `OpenProcess` is too large, you only need to use what the [`CreateRemoteThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createremotethread#parameters) document requires: `PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ`

Comment: Thank you. It explains everything. I was keep testing and when it randomly started crashing my explorer I got absolutely stunned and didn't know what was happening. Now everything works flawlessly. And yes, I am aware that PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS is overkill in my case. As I've said. I also created the target process. I don't care about being noisy or following good practices here. I just wanted it to work, so I made sure it had all permissions just to make sure that permissions weren't the problem.